# Flip vertically an Android Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

Is there an easy way to flip a canvas in Android?  I cant seem to find anything that allows me to flip it vertically so that zero on the y-axis is the bottom of the phone screen instead of the top. It's OK if the solution isn't especially fast because I'm not doing anything computationally intense with the canvas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try

```
canvas.scale(1f, -1f, width / 2f, height / 2f)
```

See [Canvas.scale](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#scale(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)) documentation.  The first two parameters are the amount to scale by.

Answer (score 0):

If you are drawing a bitmap, you can also use the `Shader.TileMode` of `MIRROR`, e.g.

```
val shader = BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)
paint.shader = shader
canvas.drawRoundRect(roundRect, 20F, 20F, mPaint)
paint.shader = null
```